# Is there a way to send notifications from phone to webbrowser

Tags: ios, iphone

This may seem like a silly question, but I am wanting to code a web extention to  display the notifications that my iphone gets in my web browser (or just store them in a database to do whatever).

I am wondering if iphone has a way to report all of its current notifications to a database without having to go from app to app to make it happen.

Comment: No, you cannot access notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly this is **not** possible. You cannot intercept notifications.

What you could do is send information about received notification to your backend when user opens the app from the notification.